# Robot Framework: wait until element disappears

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I run a test where I have to dismiss a warning that is a DIV that overlays the whole page. First I send a click to a button that adds something, then a warning is displayed. Finally I enter a string in a field

The code looks something like this

```
SeleniumLibrary.Click element  add_button
Wait Until Element is visible  warning-overlay-div
SeleniumLibrary.Click element  dismiss-warning
SeleniumLibrary.Click element  something-else
```

Running this code results in an error message:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element `<input
>   type="text" class="upperCaseClass modified" id="something-else"
>   maxlength="15" style="width: 143px; text-transform: uppercase;"> is
>   not clickable at point (230, 679). Other element would receive the
>   click: <div class="warning-overlay-div" style="width: 100%; height:
>   853px; z-index: 2003;"></div>`

That is, I can't click in *something-else* because *warning-overlay-div* is on top of it.

Ok, so I added a check to make sure the *warning-overlay-div* is gone between the the click *dismiss-warning* and the click on *something-else*. I have tried multiple variants but these three all give the same result

(from the log)

```
00:00:15.050KEYWORD SeleniumLibrary . Wait Until Element Is Not Visible ${warning-overlay-div}
00:00:15.003KEYWORD SeleniumLibrary . Wait Until Page Does Not Contain ${warning-overlay-div}
00:00:15.039KEYWORD SeleniumLibrary . Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element ${warning-overlay-div}
```

It might take half a second or so for the overlay to disappear but as you can see, all these wait until they timeout after 15 seconds before they return success. I want to continue as soon as the *warning-overlay-div* is gone, not wait 15 seconds for that.

How do I check that this overlay is gone and then immediately continue?

Comment: I would try `Wait Until Page Does Not Contain    <text of the warning overlay>`. Make sure to pass the text of the `div` and not the web element itself.

Comment: The set of keywords `Wait Until *` do not wait/sleep for 15 seconds, they do return control immediately when their condition is fulfilled. It's very strange the 3 of them are taking precisely 15 seconds to finish - are you sure they do succeed, but not fail at their timeout?

Comment: @todor The log shows green but I am absolutely not sure. In fact, I was surprised it worked. All other attempts I have tried (such as sleep) failed with the same error message as above. Do these Wait Until * return something I could look at?

Comment: As mentioned by @Todor I'm surprised that they take 15 seconds, exactly. Using a custom keyword that clicks the element and surround it with `Wait untill keyword succeeds` occasionally is a working approach.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that the default timeout is 15 seconds? See the Timeout section here http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html

Comment: Evan so, this is the timeout when the keyword "gives up" to wait on the condition, and fails

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially try using "Wait Until Keyword Succeeds" allowing yourself a custom retry timeout. Especially useful if you want to ensure the warning is removed from display in an appropriate amount of time.

```
 Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${retry}  ${retry-interval}  Element Should Not Be Visible  ${warning-overlay-div}
```

**${retry}** = the amount of time overall to perform the check

**${retry-interval}** = the time between each retry

[Time Formats](https://baishanlu.gitbooks.io/robot-framework-cn-en-user-manual/content/6appendices/65time_format.html)

(I would have made this just a comment but I cannot until I have 50rep - this is just something that might be worth trying)